# MetaWeblog vs Blogger API: How widely supported are they?

Tags: api, blogs, blogger, metaweblog

I'd like to implement one blog API and support as many blogs as possible. I understand both these APIs are semi-standards, supported by several sites.

Which blog platforms support which API?

For the Blogger API -- does the coverage vary much between versions of the API? 
Which is the best version to use if coverage is more important than having all the features?

Thanks in advance for any help! Daniel